# DbgPrint from WDK sample

Tags: c++, c, debugging, wdk

I need to call DbgPrint or KdPrint function from WDK sample `src\print\monitors\localmon`

Please help with instructions

I've just added

`#include <ntddk.h>` in localmon.c file

and

`DbgPrint("Some message");` in same file

and at compiling I've get next errors:

```
1>errors in directory c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\src\print\new2\monitors\localmon
1>c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\ntdef.h(149) : error C2220: warning treated as
error - no 'object' file generated
1>c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\ntdef.h(614) : error C2011: '_PROCESSOR_NUMBER'
 : 'struct' type redefinition
1>c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\ntdef.h(625) : error C2011: '_GROUP_AFFINITY' :
 'struct' type redefinition
1>c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\ntdef.h(882) : error C2011: '_FLOAT128' : 'stru
ct' type redefinition
1>c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\ntdef.h(933) : error C2011: '_LARGE_INTEGER' :
'union' type redefinition
1>c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\ntdef.h(951) : error C2011: '_ULARGE_INTEGER' :
 'union' type redefinition
1>c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\ntdef.h(973) : error C2011: '_LUID' : 'struct'
type redefinition
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Don't you just include the right header file (ntddk.h?) and add the call to your source? Which step are you having problems with?

Comment: I have already #include <NTDDK.h> but get many errors at compiling 1>c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\ntdef.h(149) : error C2220: warning treated as
error - no 'object' file generated
1>c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\ntdef.h(614) : error C2011: '_PROCESSOR_NUMBER'
 : 'struct' type redefinition
1>c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\ntdef.h(625) : error C2011: '_GROUP_AFFINITY' :
 'struct' type redefinition

Comment: I want to see debug messages from monitor in DebugView (and next task it's to save output to file)

Answer (score 3):

This is user-mode code. Use `OutputDebugString` instead and don't include `ntddk.h` at all. If you need to, write a little function as adapter to `OutputDebugString` as it does not take a formatting string etc. like its counterpart `DbgPrint`.

---

If you absolutely must use `DbgPrint`, it is also available from `ntdll.dll`, of course. So you could reach into that and import it from there (prototype can be found in `wdm.h` in the WDK). But I would prefer `OutputDebugString` in user-mode code.

Comment: I've replaced DbgPrint to OutputDebugString and get next error
1>errors in directory c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\src\print\zzz\monitors\localmon
1>c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\src\print\zzz\monitors\localmon\localmon.c(86) : error
C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated

Comment: Well, this error makes no sense without the warning. Despite that it may not even be related to your original question and therefore be more appropriate to post a separate question.